# Speed up the retrieving of large datasets on FireDAC intended for just be saved as Streams

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, firedac

The data retrieving of large datasets on FireDAC seems to be slower than it should be.

A SQL Server query that returns 15,000 rows is executed in 2 seconds on SQL Server Management Studio, but a FDQuery (also connected through the SQL Server Native Client) needs 12 seconds to load it. I have tried different settings on the FetchOptions (unidirectional cursor, fetch all records, ...) but I haven't been able to reduce those 12 seconds.

The only purpose for that dataset is to be saved as a stream (it's executed on a Datasnap Server that returns the data back to the client as streams to be loaded on FDMemTables).

```
FDQuery1.Open;
FDQuery1.SaveToStream(AStream, sfBinary);
FDQuery1.Close;
```

Do you know of a faster configuration to retrieve data from SQL Server that you only intend to be saved as streams (to be loaded later on FDMemTables at the client side) ?. It doesn't seem logic that even an unidirectional cursor is taking 6 times more than directly running the SQL statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the two timings you compare are comparable directly? How do you get these times? If a query has a pure execution time - taken from SQL Profiler e.g. - of 2 seconds it is understandable that there is overhead on client side before and after, is that included? Does the timing from SQL Management Studio include similar overhead?

Comment: I understand that it needs to be some overhead, because SMS only puts it on a grid while FireDAC puts it on a buffer for further accesses, but 12 seconds over 2 seconds looks a bit much overhead. Two seconds is the execution time shown on SMS when it loads it on a grid, while the 12 seconds are calculated with a TStopWatch for the Open and SaveToStream.

Comment: What I mean is: Are you sure that SSMS will not only show you the pure execution time? SSMS might 'cheat', too: When running Profiler obviously a connection is already established - same for FireDAC? - and meta information is queried while you type your staement.

Comment: Yes, I believe that it should be comparable. The connection is also already established on FireDAC (smaller queries are executed in milliseconds), and the metadata shouldn't account for 10 seconds of overhead (in fact, when I remove the Metedata on the FetchOptions the difference is negligible).

Comment: I just learned that SSMS seems to include rendering the results in the timing it provides for a query window, so it might be comparable. I noticed you include SaveToStream, how much does that account for? Is your query connected to any DB Controls just to be sure they don't interfere in timing?

Comment: To eliminate the SaveToStream overhead simply call FetchAll before and stop the time just for Open and FetchAll.

Comment: @nil and UweRaabe the overhead of the SaveToStream is very small. Switching to FecthAll and dropping the SaveToStream has gone down from 12,02 seconds to 11,28 seconds. There are no DB controls, I execute it on a Datasnap Server and I'm only sending the data back to the client through an Stream, on the client it's where I show it on DB controls.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Are you sure that those 2 seconds represent the time SSMS takes to retrieve all 15,000 rows and not just time that it takes SSMS to retrieve enough records to populate the visible grid?

Comment: @MarcGuillot you need to scroll to the last record to make sure that management studio has actually fetched all records, otherwise the shown will be only the time spent do retrieve the first few records

Comment: @Alexandre Yes, SSMS starts showing the first records as soon as is retrieving them, but only returns the execution time when it has fetched all of them. So I'm certain that those 2 seconds is for the entire dataset.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, I'm sure. SSMS starts showing the first records as soon as it gets them, as you say, but it only reports the execution time when it has fetched all of them. So I'm certain that those 2 seconds is for the entire dataset.

Comment: Does your result set contain large string fields or  XML fields? This could make behavior in SSMS and your APP different, SSMS will limit results, see Query Options > Results > Maximum Characters Retrieved. BLOB fields might also make result sets really big.

Comment: Hi @MarcGuillot.  I find the slowness of your SaveToStream compared to SS MS very puzzling.  Have you tried doing your timings in a project which does not involve the DataSnap units at all?  These days (Delphi 10, etc), DataSnap seems to come with so much baggage, I would avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Hi @MartynA, yes, I have tried a minimal VCL Forms test application, with just that query, and it does take the same amount of time to retrieve the data.